# distinct intersecting circles in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have looked at a solution posted by yaseenshaik, which seemed nice and clear, except for one line that I cannot understand and would appreciate some help here:
this is the code:

```
function sortAsc(a, b) {
 return (a - b)
}

function solution(A) {
  var counter = 0, j= 0;
  var lower = [];
  var upper = []

  for(var i=0; i < A.length; i++) {
   lower[i] =i-A[i];
   upper[i] =i+A[i];
  } 

  lower.sort(sortAsc)
  upper.sort(sortAsc)

  for(var i= 0; i<A.length; i++) { 
   while(j < A.length && upper[i] >= lower[j]){
    counter += j-i;
    j++; 
   } 
    if(counter > 10000000) return -1;
  } 

  return counter;
}
```

my question is about the line incrementing the counter.

```
counter += j-i;
```

what is the reasoning for this code?

Comment: Can you please include a link to the "*solution posted by yaseenshaik*"?

Comment: well, at the minimum, `counter += j-i` is an accumulation of total spread between valid pairs.

Comment: but why would that add to the counter of intersecting circles?

Comment: this is the link to the solution: 
    https://github.com/yaseenshaik/codility-solutions-javascript/blob/master/NumberOfDiscIntersections.md

Comment: I'm guessing that the array passed in is an array of distances?